# Using RPi to provide powered networking to USB-connected devices?

Tags: networking, usb, ios

It's possible to charge and provide wired networking to an iPhone via a special dongle.

The USB ports on an RPi3 can deliver power to a USB-attached iPhone; is it possible to also provide network via the ethernet port?

Thanks

Example dongle: [image: dongle-photo]

Comment: can you give us a link to your interesting dongle?

Comment: Do you mean can the Pi be used with a USB->Ethernet adapter, or do you mean something else involving the iPhone?